# A simple case of Graph visualization in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to simply define a model and visualize its graph in TensorBoard for initial architectural examination. Thus, I would not like to compute anything for this purpose.

In TensorFlow 1.X, it was simple to achieve inside a `tf.Session()` where I could simply `flush()` a summary file writer.

In TensorFlow 2.0, there is no `tf.Session()` and hence the question is how do I achieve it ?

The following is an example code. What additions do I need to make, in order for it to write the graph structure in TensorBoard ?

```
from nets import i3d
import tensorflow as tf

def i3d_output(model, x):
    out, _ = model(x)
    return out

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
x = tf.random.uniform(shape=(4,179,224,224,3))
model = i3d.InceptionI3d()
net = i3d_output(model, x)
train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/home/uujjwal/bmvc2019')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In graph mode use this:

```
from tensorflow.python.summary.writer.writer import FileWriter
FileWriter('logs/', graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()).close()
```

Or this:

```
tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('log/', graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()).close()
```

No need in opening session.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`

Comment: yep, forgot `tf.compat.v1`. Just updated my question

Comment: Great this one works. A speculative question but do you think that the inability to do something without using `tf.compat.v1` is a deficiency of the non-eager mode of TF2.0 ?

Comment: In TF2 you're supposed to use eager execution and that supposed to be a "good thing". You can do something like `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1` to relieve the pain :-)

Comment: It all looks like a huge crutch. Is there native for TF2.0 way to do this?

Comment: An example of TF2.0 graph visualisation without  tf.compat.v1; https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582215/2585501